# Do I paint on top of caulk?

Tags: caulk

I'm boxing in an Ikea PAX wardrobe (see picture) with MDF. I've used filler on the gaps between the wardrobe and MDF (which I'm in the process of sanding)

For the gaps between the MDF and wall I was planning on using caulk.

What I can't decide is for that "built in look" whether I should be caulking and then painting over the caulk or the caulk should go on last.

(Doors are obviously yet to go on)

When I've painted caulk in the past (after priming) I always seen to get cracking, which is why I am asking here...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Caulk first, then paint. Be sure to use a caulk labelled as 'paintable'. (in other words, not silicone.) Worth noting is that some caulking, if left unpainted, can discolor over time. (Usually, that's white going to yellow-ish.)

Cracking in the past might have been caused by not giving time for the caulk to cure. Check the instructions for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Caulk will crack if put on too thick. It shrinks slightly as it dries.

To caulk and paint or paint and then caulk is somewhat of a preference.

I make that determination base on the color/s I am dealing with.

Your furniture piece looks to be white.  If it were my project, I would paint the wall. Then do the caulking in a brite white latex caulk.

Use a big sponge like a [Grouting sponge](https://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-Extra-Large-7-1-2-in-D-x-5-1-2-in-W-Polyurethane-Sponge-for-Grouting-Cleaning-and-Washing-6-Pack-70005Q-6D/100566800?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_014_FLOOR_TOOLS-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_TOOLS_PMax_G&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_014_FLOOR_TOOLS-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_TOOLS_PMax_G-71700000102945947--&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwk6SwBhDPARIsAJ59GweWDBqaGwjz_KMulza9_dKppFEP_KKREDHx6cnN-CHg3-Lvv-qbFh8aAskCEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) to wipe the bead smooth. Wet it and wring it out for a nice looking line.